# How to create Backbone Collection from a JSON API call that returns root parameters as well as array

Tags: backbone.js

Backbone.js noob here.

I want to create a collection, from a JSON API external to my application. Specifically, the api from [Stackoverflow](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/). I know I should set the url parameter from a collection like this:

```
App.Collections.Users = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: User,
    url: "http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/users/800271;562692?jsonp=?&key=blahblah"
});
```

The problem is that the JSON API returns something like:

```
{
 "total": 2,
 "users": [
  {
   "user_id": 800271,
  },
  {
   "user_id": 800272,
  }
 ]
}
}
```

How do I ignore the "total" attribute?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If this is the only collection in your app to work with such api, all you have to do is to override `parse` method for it:

```
App.Collections.Users = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    // ...
    parse: function(resp, xhr) {
        return resp.users
    }
})
```

If you also have to save your models, maybe you will need to override `Backbone.sync`. Don't hesitate to read [backbone's source](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html): it's thoroughly annotated and easy to follow.

Comment: +1 for the link to backbone's annotated source... Fantastic resource :D