# Backbone: how to work with JSON root elements

Tags: backbone.js

I'm building a backbone frontend on top of an API, which follows this conventions: http://jsonapi.org/

So GET and POST needs an JSON root, such as:

```
{
  "posts": [{
    "id": "1",
    "title": "Rails is Omakase",
    "links": {
      "author": "9",
      "comments": [ "5", "12", "17", "20" ]
    }
  }]
}
```

When fetching collections, the entire `posts` object will be stored in the collection instead of single entries.

Do I have to override a lot of backbone functions to get models and syncing working with a RESTful API that uses JSON roots or are there functions included that I've overlooked?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7052742/382982) answer.

Comment: You may want to use something like this [backbone-jsonapi](https://github.com/guillaumervls/backbone-jsonapi) package which helps Backbone work properly with the jsonapi.org conventions and is actually listed [on their "Examples" page](http://jsonapi.org/examples/).

Comment: Thanks, but it's only designed to fetch collections/models, not for all CRUD functions.